# Create a textview with rounded corners at one side only

Tags: android

I use the following xml in my drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
</shape>
```

And this is the code for the TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/maptext"
    android:layout_width="58dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/round"
    android:text="2"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

That results in a rectangle which is curved at both sides:

Instead, I want it curved at the left side only.

Comment: Hi Aney. Welcome to StackOverflow. The corners can be set individually: android:bottomRightRadius, android:bottomLeftRadius, android:topLeftRadius, android:topRightRadius.

Answer (score 0):

In your drawable folder, you can use below drawable xml file:-

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

</shape>
```